# How to tell if NSManagedObject is saved?

Tags: ios, core-data

How can I tell whether an NSManagedObject is persisted?

(As opposed to a new object that has not beed saved yet or was deleted.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

check if its object id is persistent

```
BOOL isSaved = !object.objectID.isTemporaryID;
```

documentation about isTemporaryID:

"YES if the receiver is temporary, otherwise NO. Most object IDs return NO. New objects inserted into a managed object context are assigned a temporary ID which is replaced with a permanent one once the object gets saved to a persistent store."

Comment: It appears that in swift you have to use `.temporaryID` instead of `.isTemporaryID`

Comment: Yep, property is `temporaryID`, but getter is set to custom `isTemporaryID` - so Objective-C calls it as `[object.objectId isTemporaryID]`

Comment: But afaik, it's possible to obtain a permanent ID for an object that is not persisted yet, correct me if I'm wrong. This would lead to the answer not being deterministic :/

Comment: Added Documentation @JanNash -- I dont think so BUT I might be wrong ;) but we use this logic a lot

Comment: In swift 2.3 you have to use object.objectID.temporaryID

Comment: BUT if I call obtainPermanentIDsForObjects on this object, it will have a permanentID but not yet be saved, right?  So this test isn't guaranteed in all scenarios, right?

Comment: right. that calls is like a dry-run save. the database gets even touch on a filesystem level... isInserted might be another help [NOTE I have never used this call nor see any real use for it and dont know for sure itll break the original test]

Comment: How to insert check if objectID.isTemporaryID is false into the NSFetchRequest?

Answer (score 4):

Daij-Djan's answer works only in iOS 8.0+. For old versions use:

```
BOOL isSaved = nil != object.objectID.persistentStore;
```

Comment: No. I use it on lower oss

Comment: Hmm, strange... "Available in iOS 8.0 and later" (documentation).

Comment: Documentation bug im sure

Comment: @Andy, yep, according to `CoreData/NSManagedObjectID.h` iOS 3.0 +